# Input using getline(cin,n); is not printing first input and i am not using cin>> to take input anywhere

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, getline

I am trying to print inputs until user gives a blank input.So,I used getline(cin,input).But,When i use getline(cin,input).It is skipping first input while giving output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while(1)
    {
        string n;
        getline(cin, n);
        while(getline(cin,n) && !n.empty())
        {
            cout<<n<<endl;;
        }
        if(n.empty())
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample input:

```
12  
2
```

output obtained:

```
2
```

output needed:

```
12   
2
```

Comment: Perhaps the consecutive `getline` calls (one before the loop, one in the while-expression) has something to do with the first read disappearing. Why do you think you need the bare call at all? (or nested loops, for that matter).

Comment: The expected output wouldn't make sense to me, as would the actual output. I'd expect no output at all for that input. BTW, is the outer while-loop necessary at all to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt check the in-editor-format. The OP intended those on separate lines.

Comment: Yes, @WhozCraig, that explains a lot. I took the liberty to edit that slightly for readability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code asks line twice :

1) before nested loop

```
  getline(cin, n);
```

2) inside the condition of nested loop

```
  while(getline(cin,n) && !n.empty())
```

My suggestion is to simplify the program as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while(1)    // only one loop is needed
    {
        string n;
        getline(cin, n);   // read line
        if(n.empty())      // check line
            break;         // stop loop
        else
        {   
            cout << n << endl; // print line
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or leave only nested loop without `while(1)`, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string n;

    while(getline(cin,n) && !n.empty())
    {
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
    getline(cin, n);                         // here
    while(getline(cin,n) && !n.empty())
```

That first `getline` reads input ( the first line ), but you discard and read again in your

```
while(getline(cin,n) && !n.empty())
```

So, remove that first `getline`, that should give you the desired outcome.